# How to justify this limit (Gamma function)?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

For all $x, t \in \mathbb R_*^+$ and $n \ge 2$ such that $t < n$. And from this equation:

$\left(1-\frac t n \right)^n \times \exp\left( n \int_0^{\frac{t}{n}} \left( \frac t n - \sigma \right) \frac 1 {(1-\sigma)^2} d\sigma \right) = e^{-t}$

Prove

1) $\int_0^{\sqrt[3]n} (f(x,t)-f_n(x,t))dt = \int_0^{\sqrt[3]n} t^{x-1}e^{-t}\left[1- \exp\left( -n \int_0^{\frac{t}{n}} \left( \frac t n - \sigma \right) \frac 1 {(1-\sigma)^2} d\sigma \right)\right]$

Where $f(x,t) = t^{x-1}e^{-t}$ and $f_n(x,t)=t^{x-1}\left(1-\frac t n \right)^n$

I already proved 
$\int (f(x,t)-f_n(x,t))dt = \int t^{x-1}e^{-t}\left[1- \exp\left( -n \int_0^{\frac{t}{n}} \left( \frac t n - \sigma \right) \frac 1 {(1-\sigma)^2} d\sigma \right)\right]$.

But why $0$ to ${\sqrt[3]n}$?

2) Prove now

$\sup_{t\in[0,{\sqrt[3]n}]}\left[1- \exp\left( -n \int_0^{\frac{t}{n}} \left( \frac t n - \sigma \right) \frac 1 {(1-\sigma)^2} d\sigma \right)\right]\to_{n\to\infty} 0$.

It would be wonderful if someone can help me.
Thanks

Comment: In 1) you are just adding limits to an expression you already know, so this is fine. I think the choice of limit is to do with part 2.

In part 2 you can differentiate that expression using Liebniz integral rule and set equal to zero. Then see if the supremum tends to zero.

Comment: I've found there are no turning points in $[0, n^{1/3}]$. Hence you can evaluate at the end points and then check it tends to zero in $n$.

Comment: How to use Liebniz integral rule in this case? I don't get it sorry…

Comment: differentiate the expression in the exp. This will be the function of $(t,\sigma)$ inside of the integral, evaluated at $\sigma = $ the end points. There is also an integral term. Then you can set all of this equal to zero and solve.